# Web-Component has no content in Vue3, Quasar, Webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, web-component, quasar-framework, quasar

My environment is Vue 3.2.45 with quasar and webpack. I want to create web-components so that I can use them in this environment and in websites without any framework. I have a vue project and one without any framework. Both should look equal. I don't want to write code twice so I want to use web components.

For testing I started a new vue project ( without quasar and with vite instead of webpack). In my test-project it works.

I have a component TestComponent.ce.vue

```
<template>
   <h4>Test</h4>
   <h6>Web-Component-Test</h6>
   <p>just a comment</p>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<style scoped>
  h4 {
    color: red;
}
h6 {
    color: green;
}
p { 
    color: blue
}
</style>
```

In my main.ts is following code

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent.ce.vue'

const testComponentElement = defineCustomElement(TestComponent)

customElements.define('test-component', testComponentElement)
```

After I run npm build I can use the files in the dist folder and use following code in the code of the website without any framework and it works as expected

```
<script type="module" src="./dist/assets/index-xxx.js"></script>
<test-component></test-component>
```

But when I use the same code with Vue, Quasar and Webpack it doesn't work. There are no errors in the console and the content of the web component is empty.

Has someone an idea where the mistake is or has someone a working tutorial for web-components with vue, quasar and webpack?